# get the changed records from an update all in ruby

Tags: ruby, rails-activerecord

In postgresql this works

```
update products set status = 1 
where status <> 1 and updated_at < '2014-04-01'
returning id;
```

This is most handy because I get the id's of all the records I've just updated.

Is there a way to do this in active record?
I am trying (very hard) to be more of a ruby guy.
I am finding the leaky abstraction in cases like this a bit hard.

I understand that update_all returns the count.
Is there a call that allows for the returning?

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 4:

```
Product.where('updated_at < ? and not status = ?', '2014-04-01', 1).map do |product|
  product.update_attribute(:status, 1)
  product.id
end
```

Comment: Some part of that needs correction - OP asks `status <> 1`(not equals to), while you are finding `status = 1`. Also, OP needs to update that record, you are just changing the object but not saving the changes. :)

Answer (score 0):

For **Rails <4**,you can write something like this

```
Product.where('updated_at < ? and status != ?', '2014-04-01', 1).map do |product|
product.update_attribute(:status, 1)
product.id
```

**OR**

```
Product.where('updated_at < ? and status NOT IN (?)', '2014-04-01', 1).map do |product|
product.update_attribute(:status, 1)
product.id
```

**OR**

```
Product.find(:all, :conditions => ['updated_at < ? and status NOT IN (?)', '2014-04-01', 1]).map do |product|
product.update_attribute(:status, 1)
product.id
```